# In clinical trials, what is the benefit of using a composite rather than individual outcome

Tags: treatment-effect, clinical-trials

I have read that composite outcomes are common in cardiovascular trials because they give a holistic view of a treatment effect. Assuming outcomes are frequent enough for statistical power to not be an issue, why would this be the case? Wouldn't it always be beneficial to measure the effect of treatment on outcomes individually?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a new treatment that you expect to reduce the risk of heart attack (acute MI), but that you worry might cause an increase in deaths from non-cardiovascular causes. This was exactly the situation with the statin drugs when they were new.

Using acute MI as the outcome would measure the intended effect of the treatment, but it would miss any increase in deaths from other causes.  You might decide you wanted to use a composite of all-cause mortality and non-fatal MI, to capture both issues.

You could measure non-fatal MI, coronary death, and death from other causes as separate outcomes (and, of course, you *would* measure them all separately). But you'd still need to specify some preferred way of combining them, and that isn't meaningfully different from having a composite outcome.

Another setting is where other interventions are part of the composite outcome.  If you are trying to prevent heart attacks (or even just reduce coronary atherosclerosis) and a trial participant gets their coronary arteries cleaned out (angioplasty) or gets new coronary arteries (CABG), how do you count that?  It's undesirable to treat them as lost to follow-up, but it's also a bit strange to ignore the intervention.  It's fairly common to add angioplasty and CABG as part of the (bad) outcome.  This is a bit more controversial, but you can see the reasoning.

Two further notes

- it's not always unambiguous whether something is a composite outcome. If you expect to present death from cardiovascular causes, and that would be your preferred outcome, is death from any cause a composite outcome or not?
- statistical power is *always* an issue in randomised trials to some extent, because it's unethical to randomise more people than you need to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer (It’s interesting to hear about the historical context, I’ll read up on it)! I just had a couple of follow up questions: 1) why do we have to specify some preferred way of combining them, isn’t it ok to just have separate effect estimates?: not sure if I’m missing something obvious here ; 2) if frequencies of events or if it is plausible to assume before that treatment effects are different across outcomes, would it still make sense to combine them?

Comment: In the end, your decisions about whether the new treatment is Good or Bad will require combining them. In principle that could be left to the individual patient, but there's a strong norm in favour of having a primary outcome in clinical trials.   And, yes, my first example is one where you would definitely expect the the effects to be different across outcomes, and that's *why* it's important to combine them, to assess the tradeoff.